# How will USA vote on 2015 "UN Resolution against the US embargo on Cuba"?

Tags: united-states, international-law, international-relations, united-nations, cuba

The UN General Assembly has, from 1992, passed a resolution each year criticizing the ongoing impact of the embargo against Cuba.

That year, 59 countries voted **for** an end to the embargo, 3 voted **against**, and there were 71 **abstentions**.
The support to end the embargo has been growing steadily. In 1993, there were 88 votes **for**. In 1994, 101 voted **for**...
In [2014 there were 188 votes **for**, and just 2 voted **against** (USA and Israel)](http://www.un.org/press/en/2014/ga11574.doc.htm).

Since last december, USA and Cuba are restoring relations, including the mutual reopening of embassies in Havana and Washington. Besides, President Barack Obama is asking Congress to put an end to the embargo.

So, what will be the USA vote at this resolution on the next UN General Assembly on September 2015? Is this vote a prerrogative of the President (in this case, of Barack Obama)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires someone with a time machine or access to material non-public information to be able to answer.

Comment: You may be right. 
I still "feel" this question carries some weight in the sense of how much awareness a change in this vote (even an abstention) could arise. Anyway, I did a [related (maybe a better) question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/does-the-average-american-knows-that-the-embargo-on-cuba-is-unpopular-around-t)

Answer (score 3):

I have no privileged information and cannot predict what will happen but I would be quite surprised if the US would vote for an end of the embargo or even abstain.

At the end of the day, even if such a vote has basically no consequences, it's still a kind of interference in the US own decision-making process, something no country can accept or condone. From this perspective, it's perfectly coherent for the president to wish the embargo to end and yet to object to the fact that other countries are criticising it or officially demanding its end.

Personally, I always found the embargo silly but when it comes to a vote at the UN, I still don't see how the US could do anything but oppose any resolution against it. By doing so, it's simply defending its ability to decide sovereignly over the matter and its own institutions, including the fact that in the US, the authority to end the embargo rests with the US Congress.

From a domestic point-of-view, airing internal disagreements on the international stage never plays well and it's likely that it would be especially controversial in the US and with this president (cf. all the controversies about some mundane gestures Obama makes during official visits). So except if there is something important to win (as with the recent agreement with Iran), I don't see the president risking any political capital on such a move.

It's even more guesswork but I would venture that even the Cubans understand this and don't care all that much.

Comment: I understand the point of "its ability to decide sovereignly" versus "airing internal disagreements on the international stage". 

Not so much about "such a vote has basically no consequences". Even Cuba knew that approve this resolution without US support would not have been direct consequence in US. But, as a lot of UN "elections" (as such with certain veto), it raises awareness. 

The average american knows how much the embargo on Cuba is unpopular around the world? For example, what percentage of people at US knows that UN has approved this resolution 33 years in a row since 1992?

Comment: @curiouser Even in this respect, I don't think it changes much (it's happening every year!) but my point was mainly that is has no direct legal consequences.

Comment: It is changing international awareness (the first time, in 1992 there were just 59 votes **for**, until 2014 when there were 188 votes **for**). So, a change in this vote (even just **abstain**) would generate news, then awareness to the domestic public.

To assess the actual "average American" awareness, I've made this [new other question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/does-the-average-american-knows-that-the-embargo-on-cuba-is-unpopular-around-t)

Comment: @curiouser I think you are vastly overestimating the influence of these things.

Comment: Good answer, but surprisingly enough, US (and Israel) abstained one year after this question&answer https://news.un.org/en/story/2016/10/543832-us-abstains-first-time-annual-un-vote-ending-embargo-against-cuba